# Arduino C++ calculating trigger points

Tags: c++, arduino

Can someone please help me with code? I have a 24 teeth trigger wheel. Every tooth is registered by hall sensor and I need that Arduino simulate 36 pulse output of that corresponding 24 pulse input.

Here is my code with delayMicroseconds, but I can`t use delayMicroseconds, because Arduino doesn't understand bigger than 16k micros delay.

```
const int  hall = 2;    // hall sensor
const int ledPin = 13;       // the pin that the LED is attached to

// Variables will change:
int teethCounter = 0;
int hallState = 0;
int lasthallState = 0;
long cycles=0;
boolean cycle = false;
unsigned long microsStart = 0;
unsigned long microsStop = 0;
unsigned long usElapsed = 0;
unsigned long usElapsedUp = 0;
unsigned long usInterval;


void setup() {
// initialize the button pin as a input:
pinMode(hall, INPUT);
// initialize the LED as an output:
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
// initialize serial communication:
Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() {
hallState = digitalRead(hall);
if(cycle==true){
microsStart=micros();
}
if(cycle==true){
usInterval = usElapsedUp/72;
for (int i=0; i <= 36; i++){
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(usInterval);
digitalWrite(13,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(usInterval);
cycle = false;
}
}

// compare the hallState to its previous state
if (hallState != lasthallState) {
// if the state has changed, increment the counter
if (hallState == HIGH) {
  teethCounter++;
  if(teethCounter==24){
    cycle = true;
    cycles++;
    teethCounter=0;
    usElapsedUp = usElapsed;

  }

  Serial.print("Tooth count: ");
  Serial.print(teethCounter);
  Serial.print(" Cycles: ");
  Serial.print(cycles);
  Serial.print(" Time: ");
  Serial.print(usElapsedUp);
  Serial.print(" Interval: ");
  Serial.println(usInterval);
  }
   microsStop=micros();
   usElapsed=microsStop-microsStart;
  }
 // save the current state as the last state,
 //for next time through the loop

   lasthallState = hallState;
   }
```

How can I calculate and from where can I take trigger points?

```
If(event happens==true){
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
}
If(event happens==false){
digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}
```

[If it helps to understand here is a block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNgRV.jpg)

Comment: You need some kind of function that converts from 24 to 36; as this is not a 1:1 mapping.  Where do the extra 12 pulses come from?

Comment: Do you want to convert from the 24 pulse *frequency* to a 36 pulse frequency?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

As long as you understand that you will never be able get 36 pulses per turn accuracy with 24 pulse/turn, you can do this, which is a common trick derived from the Bresenham algorithm.  This solution assumes you are concerned about the position.

Now, this will generate pulses in real-time, as opposed to your code, which generates pulses in a blocking manner, I don't think losing pulses was your original intent.

This code will not generate pulses uniformly, 1 out of 3 readings will generate 2 pulses.

Another way would be to calculate the average speed and program a hardware timer to simulate the 36 pulses per turn, using interrupts, but going that route would likely (invariably, in my experience) end up in total loss of sync between the actual position of the wheel and what your corrected tick count reports.  There are also strict speed ranges that you have to respect if going that route, also this will introduce severe *latency* issues to your application.

1. Change the increment value to 36, and the whole turn count to 24/36.
2. Change the step detection to a threshold of 24.
3. I'm trying to understand why you want to do this 36/24 thing, and can't.

So, your mileage may vary.

```
// compare the hall State to its previous state
// to declared outside of loop()
// int smallCounter;
// PULSE_WIDTH as small positive pulse with in us
//
if (hallState != lasthallState) {
  // if the state has changed, increment the counter
  smallCounter += ((hallState == HIGH) ? 36 : 0);
  // ... I'm assuming that the serial prints you had here were just here for debugging.
  lasthallState = hallState;
}
//
// reporting for each step below
//
if (smallCounter >= 24)
{
  smallCounter -= 24;
  if (++teethCounter >= 36) {
    cycle = true;
    cycles++;
    teethCounter=0;
    usElapsedUp = usElapsed;

  }
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(PULSE_WIDTH);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(PULSE_WIDTH); // this is probably not needed.
}
```